# Mysqld [v5.0.51a] repeatedly restarting upon call to stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm repeatedly getting this in my server error log for MySQld. On my PHP (MySQLi) or SQL client (not sure what they use, maybe MySQLi as well) calling *some* (not all) stored procedures, this happens and I get the error message "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" (repeatedly). This procedure did actually work yesterday ;(. Thanks.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
090508 10:18:43       1 Connect     validuser@user-5440b1b4.wfd77a.dsl.pol.co.u$
                      1 Query       BEGIN
090508 10:18:44       1 Query       call `test_graphstats`(1, 'gbp', 'MONTH')
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem with one of the lines in the SQL, where I was calling one of my own stored functions. So, I guess a trial and error approach is required.

In fact, my stored function required two arguments, when I was only providing one. Calling the second argument with NULL fixed this.